# ASP .NET how do i reference a HTML link from my domain?

Tags: asp.net, view, hyperlink

I have this class "Firma", it has 3 attributes, all strings. But I want the attribute FirmaUrl to be a URL? What type should this be, and how do I put this as a parameter in the constuctor?

The code:

```
    public class Firma
   {
    public int FirmaId { get; set; }
    public string Naam{ get; set;   }
    public string FirmaUrl { get; set; }
    public string Contactemail { get; set; }

    public Firma()
    {

    }

    public Firma(string naam, string firmaurl, string contactemail)
    {
        Naam = naam;
        FirmaUrl = firmaurl;
        Contactemail = contactemail;
    }


}
```

Initializing this:

```
Firma Hogent = new Firma("Hogent", "www.hogent.be", "hogent@mail.be");
```

The view:

```
         <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firma.Naam)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firma.Naam)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firma.Contactemail)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firma.Contactemail)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firma.FirmaUrl)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firma.FirmaUrl)
        </dd>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A URL would be a string.  You already have a string, and it's already on the constructor.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want it to show up as a clickable link in my view. But now I realise i should just use basic html markup.. I'm a dumbass, always overcomplicating things..

Answer (score 0):

Jarne, you can use the @Html.ActionLink to make it clickable.
(see intellisense to find out what you need to set within this ActionLink)

Comment: Hi I tried this but it links to my own site: 
            
               @Html.ActionLink(Model.Firma.FirmaUrl, Model.Firma.FirmaUrl)
            `

This is the link that it ends up with /Catalogus/www.hogent.be

Comment: if i use this:     <a href=@Model.Firma.FirmaUrl>Test</a>
It still links to this: http://localhost:58049/Catalogus/Details/www.hogent.be
And i want it to just link to www.hogent.be, any idea how i fix this?

Comment: Okay, outside your own domain..
Then indeed i would use a regular href.
Example:
<a href="@Model.Firma.FirmaUrl" target="_blank">@Model.Firma.FirmaUrl</a>
Be sure that FirmaUrl contains the http:// part.
(else it perhaps cant identify it)